# Error creating archive applications ios

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, archive

Before updated xcode, everything was fine, but now I get a lot of errors. These errors mean that I do not have certificates, but I check the Member Center, I have everything. Can anyone write a step by step what to do? It would have helped. Picture errors:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQp2O.png

Comment: Maybe check on the Member Center that in your App ID the right Application Services (like iCloud) are enabled. (Don't forget to re-generate provisioning profile if you change something in App ID settings.)

Comment: All right, If I correctly understood? (http://cs628831.vk.me/v628831778/22a8/HV7ookhTX0Y.jpg)

Comment: I think you use xCode beta version. if yes than please install full version.

Comment: xCode beta version - 4 version, i use xcode 6.3.2. I try to write in support

Comment: And in Build Settings => Code Signing Identity : right Provisioning Profiles are selected ?

Comment: Yes (http://cs628831.vk.me/v628831778/22c8/T6NplRqwjXE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this method since iOS2.1 and usually works is:

- right click your project
- "show package contents"
- edit project.pbxproj
- search for every "PROVISIONING_PROFILE" occurrence AND delete ALL the line.
- the same for "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY"
- close Xcode and reopen
- set provising profile again.